# How to use BETWEEN condition in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

code:

```
$salarymin = 200000;
$salarymax = 500000;
$title = java;

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('job');
$where = "((salary_range_min='".$salarymin."') and (salary_range_max='".$salarymax."')) and (job_title like '".$title."%' or skill like '%".$title."%')";
$this->db->where($where);
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

In my table `job` I have defined `salary_range_min and salary_range_max`.

How to get data where salary between `200000 and 500000`?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

```
$this->db->where('salary >', 200000);
$this->db->where('salary <', 500000);
$result = $this->db->get('job')->result_array();
```

Note: 'salary' is column name. If it is different, simply change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('salary_range_min >= ',$salarymin)
$this->db->where('salary_range_max <= ',$salarymax)
$this->db->where('job_title like '.$title.'% or skill like %'.$title.'%');
// OR */
$this->db->where('job_title like '.$title.'% or skill like %'.$title.'%',FALSE);
// OR */
$this->db->where('job_title like '.$title.'% or skill like %'.$title.'%',NULL);
```

you can call where method more than one time. and you can put it as you want.
if you wanna read the generated query just after your hole statement 
Write:

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

For better idea of your statement

Answer (score -1):

```
$where = "((salary_range_min <= '".$salarymin."') and (salary_range_max >= '".$salarymax."'))";
$like = "(job_title like '".$title."%' or skill like '%".$title."%')";
$this->db->like($like);
$this->db->where($where, null, false);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.